# Microsoft NAV webservice from codeunit

Tags: web-services, soap, navision

I have a function `CalcAvailableBalance(VAR AccountNo : Code[50])` that only returns the AccountNo. 
I'm performing computations within the function and would also want to return these values in the SOAP response

Current

`<Soap:Envelope>
   <Soap:Body>
      <CalcAvailableBalance_Result xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MyCodeUnit">
         <accountNo>002001411901</accountNo>
      </CalcAvailableBalance_Result>
   </Soap:Body>
</Soap:Envelope>`

Expected

`<Soap:Envelope xmlns:Soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Soap:Body>
      <CalcAvailableBalance_Result xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MyCodeUnit">
         <accountNo>002001411901</accountNo>
         <accountBal>345555</accountBal>
         <currency>UGX</currency>
    </CalcAvailableBalance_Result>
   </Soap:Body>
</Soap:Envelope>`

Comment: And the problem is???

Comment: Can't figure out how to return the extra values without passing them as function parameters. (novice NAV developer). The codeunit only returns the values of parameters

Comment: Use XMLport as var parameter. Function will return everything that port outputs.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nav/2009/11/06/using-xmlports-with-web-services/